# Loop through all the rows of a temp table and call a stored procedure for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, foreach

I have declared a temp table to hold all the required values as follows:

```
    DECLARE @temp TABLE
    (
    Password INT,
    IdTran INT,
    Kind VARCHAR(16)
    )

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT  s.Password, s.IdTran, 'test'
from signal s inner join vefify v 
    on s.Password = v.Password 
and s.IdTran = v.IdTran 
and v.type = 'DEV' 
where s.[Type] = 'start' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM signal s2
            WHERE s.Password = s2.Password 
            and s.IdTran = s2.IdTran 
            and s2.[Type] = 'progress' )

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT  s.Password, s.IdTran, 'test'
FROM signal s inner join vefify v 
    on s.Password = v.Password 
and s.IdTran = v.IdTran 
and v.type = 'PROD' 
where s.[Type] = 'progress' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM signal s2
            WHERE s.Password = s2.Password 
            and s.IdTran = s2.IdTran 
            and s2.[Type] = 'finish' )
```

Now i need to loop through the rows in the @temp table and and for each row call a sp that takes all the parameters of @temp table as input.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does your proc return multiple or single row for each value in @temp table. if proc returns only single row/value I would condider rewriting this to call function. This way you can execute for every value in the table without `cursors` = `CURSES` or `LOOPS`. SQL is meant to do set based processing not loops. Most people in community will avoid everything that has to to with `cursors` it is really a `curse`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

you could use a cursor:

```
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @pass varchar(100)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, Password FROM @temp
OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id, @pass

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    EXEC mysp @id, @pass ... -- call your sp here
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id, @pass
END

CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: How do i pass in the Password, IdTran, Kind from the @temp into the stored proc?

Comment: Awesome works great! I am curious if there a way to do this without using the cursor? Would it be more efficient without the cursor(This will be running for hundreds of thousands of records)?

Comment: I don't think you can do that without a cursor. Cursors have somewhat of a bad reputation but they are not that inefficient. If your temp table is few thousand rows I wouldn't worry...

Comment: The @FETCH_STATUS variable is a typo.  It is supposed to be @@FETCH_STATUS (2 ampersands).  I tried editing the above script, but SO needs edits to be 6 chars or more.

Comment: You are wonderful people! This answer was perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Try returning the dataset from your stored procedure to your datatable in C# or VB.Net.  Then the large amount of data in your datatable can be copied to your destination table using a Bulk Copy.  I have used BulkCopy for loading large datatables with thousands of rows, into Sql tables with great success in terms of performance.

You may want to experiment with BulkCopy in your C# or VB.Net code.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
DECLARE maxval, val, @ind INT;
SELECT MAX(ID) as maxval FROM table;

while (ind <= maxval  ) DO           

      select `value` as val from `table` where `ID`=ind;

      CALL fn(val);

      SET ind = ind+1;
end while;
```

Comment: OP is using MS SQL.  What you've provided here wouldn't run in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    Declare @min int=0, @max int =0 --Initialize variable here which will be use in loop 
    Declare @Recordid int,@TO nvarchar(30),@Subject nvarchar(250),@Body nvarchar(max)  --Initialize variable here which are useful for your

    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Recordid] )  AS Rownumber, Recordid, [To], [Subject], [Body], [Flag]
            into #temp_Mail_Mstr FROM Mail_Mstr where Flag='1'  --select your condition with row number & get into a temp table

    set @min = (select MIN(Rownumber) from #temp_Mail_Mstr); --Get minimum row number from temp table
    set @max = (select Max(Rownumber) from #temp_Mail_Mstr);  --Get maximum row number from temp table

   while(@min <= @max)
   BEGIN
        select @Recordid=Recordid, @To=[To], @Subject=[Subject], @Body=Body from #temp_Mail_Mstr where Rownumber=@min

        -- You can use your variables (like @Recordid,@To,@Subject,@Body) here  
        -- Do your work here 

        set @min=@min+1 --Increment of current row number
    END
```

Answer (score -3):

You always don't need a cursor for this. You can do it with a while loop. You should avoid cursors whenever possible. While loop is faster than cursors.

Comment: What are you talking about, mate ?

Comment: What are you asking my friend? You think you always need a cursor?

Comment: I am not saying your claims are incorrect. I'm saying you gave a bad answer. You don't explain anything or give pointers on where to find more information. Your answer does not help in any way.