# Executing stored procedure for each line in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Good day,

I'm figuring out a legacy procedure and ran into something, which should be easy but does not compute with me, at least not today.

The logic I'm after is I have values in **table1**, which I wish to feed to stored procedure **proc1** and save the results to **Table2**.

Currently this is called by different users manually filling in the strings which populate the variables.  working syntax is for instance:

`exec [dbo].[Proc1] @var1=N'10010015',@var2='2008-03-31 00:00:00', @var3=50000`

I tried something like

```
declare var1 varchar, var2 varchar, var3 int
insert into table2 (result1, result2, result3) 
Select * from 
[dbo].[Proc1] (
  select @var1 = var1_tab1, 
         @var2 = var2_tab1 
         from table1
)
```

With regular function I'd just feed it the variables in correct order, but the procedure requires the @var1 formats. And I am not allowed to alter the function.

Previous try just gives me *incorrect syntax*. Any ideas how to approach this sort of issue would be appreciated. .

---

**Edit: **

Yeah, it's a duplicate. Or at least I used the other to create solution.

Way too much writing. Too long did not read. The following below worked.

Things that I did not understand, but now make sense:

-You can execute procedures without explicitly setting the variables as long as input is same order as the procedure definition.

-You can just insert the results to table because return (from this specific procedure) is select.

```
DECLARE @var1 int, 
@var2 int,
@var3 float,
@var4 datetime,

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT var1, var2, var3, var4 FROM table1
OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @var1, @var2, @var3, @var4

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    insert into table2   EXEC [procedure] @var1, @var2, @var3, 0, '', NULL, @var4
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @var1, @var2, @var3, @var4
END

CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through all the rows of a temp table and call a stored procedure for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618968/loop-through-all-the-rows-of-a-temp-table-and-call-a-stored-procedure-for-each-r)

Comment: Search before posting - always. [Passing columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618968/loop-through-all-the-rows-of-a-temp-table-and-call-a-stored-procedure-for-each-r/22619085) of a table as parameters to a stored procedure is a common question, as is [inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table) the resultset.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is a function used with cross apply. You cannot call an SP in a select statement. Try writing your SP as a function.

Comment: What does this SP actually do? Interating through each row in a table is going to be slow. Dependingon what it's doing, it may well be easier to use something else, like a in-line table value function. Without knowing what `[proc1]` does though, I can't offer much more.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done using a dynamic SQL **without a loop**.

```
    DECLARE @T1 TABLE (Col1 NVARCHAR(10), Col2 NVARCHAR(10) , Col3 INT)
    /*Sample Data*/
    INSERT INTO @T1 (Col1 ,Col2, Col3 )
    SELECT '100100' , CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),120), 5000
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '100200' , CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE),120), 6000
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '103200' , CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),CAST(GETDATE()-2 AS DATE),120), 7000
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '103400' , CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),CAST(GETDATE()-3 AS DATE),120), 9000

    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
    SELECT @Sql+= 'EXEC YourSP @Var1 ='''+T.Col1+''' , @Var2 = '''+T.Col2+''' , @var3 = '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),T.Col3)+';'+CHAR(10)     
    FROM @T1 T
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample tables with data and Stored Procedure

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.table1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE table1

CREATE TABLE table1 (var1 VARCHAR(20),var2 VARCHAR(20),var3 INT)

INSERT INTO Table1 
SELECT '10010015','2008-03-31 00:00:00','50000' UNION ALL
SELECT '10010025','2008-03-21 00:00:00','40000' UNION ALL
SELECT '10010035','2008-03-29 00:00:00','50000' UNION ALL
SELECT '10010045','2008-03-30 00:00:00','60000' UNION ALL
SELECT '10010055','2008-03-28 00:00:00','70000'

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.table2') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE table2
CREATE TABLE table2 (result1 VARCHAR(10),result2 VARCHAR(10),result3 INT )


IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Proc1') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE Proc1
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1
(
 @var1 VARCHAR(10)
,@var2 VARCHAR(20)
,@var3 INT
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO table2 (result1, result2, result3) 
SELECT @var1, @var2 ,@var3

END
GO
```

Using Dynamic Sql and While loop we will feed the parameters to sp one by in sequence saved the executed result in table2

```
DECLARE   @var1 varchar(10)
         ,@var2 varchar(20)
         ,@var3 INT 
         ,@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
         ,@MInID INT
         ,@MaxID INT

;WIth Cte
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY var1) AS Id,* FROM table1
)
SELECT @MInID = MIN(ID ),@MaxID = MAX(ID ) FROM cte

WHILE (@MInID<=@MaxID)
BEGIN
        ;WIth Cte
        AS
        (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY var1) AS Id,* FROM table1
        )
        SELECT @var1=var1,@var2=var2,@var3=var3 
        FROM cte WHERE ID=@MInID

        SET @SQL='
        EXEC [dbo].[Proc1] @var1='''+CAST(@var1 AS VARCHAR(10))+''',@var2='''+CAST(@var2 AS VARCHAR(20))+''', @var3='+CAST(@var3 AS VARCHAR(10))
        PRINT @SQL
        EXEC(@SQL)
        SET @MInID=@MInID+1
END
```

Go

```
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Result

```
result1         result2          result3
------------------------------------------
10010015    2008-03-31 00:00:00  50000
10010025    2008-03-21 00:00:00  40000
10010035    2008-03-29 00:00:00  50000
10010045    2008-03-30 00:00:00  60000
10010055    2008-03-28 00:00:00  70000
```

Answer (score 0):

With such a sample data & procedure:

```
-- CREATE FAKE PROCEDURE AS AN EXAMPLE:
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyProcedure]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
GO
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure] @A1 varchar(1),@A2 varchar(1),@id INT
AS BEGIN
    --switch chars, and multiplay intiger:
    SELECT @A2,@A1,@id*10
END
GO

--CREATE TABLES:
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (var1 VARCHAR(1), var2 VARCHAR(1), var3 INT)
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (res1 VARCHAR(1), res2 VARCHAR(1), res3 INT)
-- START DATA:
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES ('a','b',1),('m','n',2),('x','y',3)
SELECT * from @table1
```

*output @**table1**:*

```
var1 var2 var3
---- ---- ----
a    b    1
m    n    2
x    y    3
```

The solution can be achieved by using a `CURSOR`:

```
DECLARE @var1 varchar(20)
DECLARE @var2 varchar(20)
DECLARE @var3 int

DECLARE @Cursor as CURSOR;
SET @Cursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT var1, var2, var3 
    FROM @table1

OPEN @Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @var1, @var2, @var3;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @table2 (res1, res2, res3)
        EXEC MyProcedure @var1, @var2, @var3

    FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @var1, @var2, @var3;
END

CLOSE @Cursor;
DEALLOCATE @Cursor;


select * from @table2
```

Output: @**table2***

```
res1 res2 res3
---- ---- ----
b    a    10
n    m    20
y    x    30
```

**NOTE**: Both two parts above should be run together as a single query

After all: Drop *fake* procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
```